# If I have a fire damage weapon, but primary is cold based, which element am I?

Tags: diablo-iii

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Lipton-1319/hero/65560837

I'm a Demon Hunter with **[Yangs Recurve](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/yangs-recurve)** which does up to 1423 Fire damage, however for my primary resource generator **[Evasive fire](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire)**, I'm using the Focus rune which makes it Cold damage.

So when I shoot with Evasive fire, do I do fire, cold or both damage at the same time?

Comment: There was once a situation when not all skills (especially Physical) changed weapon damage to skill element, but it has been since patched out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element on your weapon doesn't matter, nor is it affected by elemental damage.
**The element of your attack is chosen by the rune** (or in case of legendary effects granting effect of all runes - by highest elemental dmg), so your attack is amplified by %cold damage.